# Will Signing up for Yahoo Directory Significantly Improve SERP for a Flex Site?

Tags: yahoo, directory-listing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SEO: What are SEO benefits of submitting to Yahoo Directory?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15422/seo-what-are-seo-benefits-of-submitting-to-yahoo-directory)

Is Yahoo Directory worth the $299? Will it generate any traffic?

I've got a Flex 3 site, so unfortunately, I'm invisible in SEO terms. I was wondering if signing up for this would help.

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yahoo's directory is a mere shadow of what it used to be. It doesn't deliver any traffic anymore. General consensus that I've read online is that it isn't worth the $299 anymore. Especially since it now now per year as opposed to a one time fee like it originally was.

[This page](http://www.websitepublisher.net/blog/2008/03/08/how-i-do-directory-submissions/) might be a good read for you.

Comment: Hi John Conde, Thank you for the advice. I'd give you a vote up, but I don't have enough rep points yet as I joined one minute ago.

Comment: No worries..  :)

Comment: @Laxmidi - you do now ;)