# SEO: What are SEO benefits of submitting to Yahoo Directory?

Tags: seo, google, yahoo

How important is Yahoo Directory these days for SEO?
It was important maybe 5 years ago, but what about today?

Answer (score 3):

It's not worth much today. Yahoo's popularity used to mean it had lots of links pointing to its pages and thus it was relevant for many topics and its directory pages would show up well in search results. Those days are long gone and the value those links carried went with it. For a directory link it's relatively valuable but overall its worth is not significant and almost certainly not worth the cost of buying that link.

Comment: Hi John.  Can you provide some references or evidence to back this up?  Sincerely, Steve.